# scroll to some section in another page after clicking a link

Tags: html

As the title says, what I want to do is after clicking a link I go to some section in another page, and that section should scroll to top. Also, I don't want to use jquery for this, I only want to use html. Thanks! following is the code from the original page:

```
<TABLE cellspacing="11px" style="margin-left:3px">
               <TR>
                  <TD><A href="detail.html#patents">PATENT</A></TD>
                  <TD><A href="detail.html#trademarks">TRADEMARKS</A></TD>
                  <TD><A href="detail.html#ipLawAndPolicy">IP LAW & POLICY</A></TD>
                  <TD><A href="detail.html#productsAndServices">PRODUCTS & SERVICES</A></TD>
                  <TD><A href="detail.html#inventors">INVENTORS</A></TD>
                  <TD><A href="detail.html#newsAndNotices">NEWS & NOTICES</A></TD>
                  <TD><A href="detail.html#faqs">FAQs</A></TD>
               </TR>
            </TABLE>
```

Following is the code from target page:

```
<BODY>
      <P id="patents">PATENTS</P>
      <HR />
      <P id="trademarks">TRADEMARKS</P>
      <HR />
      <P id="ipLawAndPolicy">IP LAW & POLICY</P>
      <HR />
      <P id="productsAndServices">PRODUCTS & SERVICES</P>
      <HR />
      <P id="inventors">INVENTORS</P>
      <HR />
      <P id="newsAndNotices">NEWS & NOTICES</P>
      <HR />
      <P id="faqs">FAQs</P>
   </BODY>
```

Comment: By "scroll", you mean *animated* scroll? Or just pop!, go to that section of the content?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to jump to a specific section of the page use the following code at the target:

```
<a name="targetName"/>
```

And link to targetPage.html#targetName. targetName here is just an example, use something appropriate for the section you are linking to.

If you need to add whitespace to the bottom of the target page you can do something like adding the following to the bottom of the page (before `</body>`):

```
<div style="height: 1000px"></div>
```

Comment: Hi epsaion, thanks for your answer, but my problem is I want the specific section go to the top, and my content on the second page doesn't fit the whole screen.

Comment: In order to do that, you will have to add whitespace at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need HTML Bookmarks:

http://www.ezineasp.net/post/HTML-Anchor-Bookmark-Tag-Links.aspx
http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/html-basics/4

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your answer, but my problem is I want the specific section go to the top, and my content on the second page doesn't fit the whole screen.

Comment: You want to MOVE portions of a page?  Why not have multiple pages with the desired section at the top?